# Manage build number Python script

Tags: python, git, version-control

I am writing an extensive Python script on my laptop. At every major change, I commit and push the project into a Git directory.

I have a virtual machine on Azure where I clone the repository and run the script. The script sometimes runs for more than a day and while it’s running, it may happen that I push some changes in the git repository.

At the beginning of the script, I would like to print a build number that uniquely identifies a version of the script, so that I am aware of what version it’s running.

What is the conventional way to do so? I don’t want to do it manually, of course.

Comment: You could display `git describe --always` output, or `git rev-list --first-parent --count @` if you're never comparing results from different histories.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the script, modify the script as part of the deploy process to include the commit id from which it was deployed.

That might look like this:

First, we assume that your script contains a line like:

```
BUILD_ID=development
```

When we copy the script to its installed destination, we use `sed` to update that line to include the commit id:

```
build_id="$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
sed "/^BUILD_ID=/ s/=.*/=$build_id/" myscript.sh > /path/to/installed/myscript.sh
chmod 755 /path/to/installed/myscript.sh
```

Stick that logic in your Makefile or install scripts.